# several lines appearing when using exception handling to prevent system from crashing

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, error-handling

I am trying to use exception handling to prevent my system from crashing, I used the below codes where this csv file does not actually exist. But the system is is continuously giving me the answer. Can someone help me to correct my codes please....help me please

These are my source codes:

```
while True:
    try:
        import pandas as pd  # data processing, csv file I/O(e.g pd.read_csv)

        df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv')
        print(df)
    except Exception as err:
            print("Uh oh, please send me this message: '{}'" .format(err))
```

the results:

```
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
Uh oh, please send me this message: '[Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv''
..................
```

Comment: Why do you have the code in a `while True` block? If there's a reason for it not included in the example, you can add a `break` in the `except` block to exit the loop in  case of an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Catching an expection means your system does not exit with the appropriate error code. Instead, it does whatever you put in your exception line and continues execution of your code. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

> If an exception occurs during execution of the try clause, the rest of
>   the clause is skipped. Then if its type matches the exception named
>   after the except keyword, the except clause is executed, and then
>   execution continues after the try statement.

This is why you never leave the while loop. This is a quick fix to the looping:

```
while True:
    try:
        import pandas as pd  # data processing, csv file I/O(e.g pd.read_csv)

        df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv')
        print(df)
    except Exception as err:
        print("Uh oh, please send me this message: '{}'" .format(err))
        break
```

Further adjustments are dependent on what you want to do if your csv is not found.